# How to require the index.php URL in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have my index page in an email folder, complete URL being: `www.bragtools.com/email/index.php`. I want to make it `www.bragtools.com/email/`, so that the search engines recognise it as a simple URL instead of a PHP page.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us what you have in your .htaccess file right now and explain what's the thing you need help with, as you forgot to ask a question?

Comment: There is nothing apart from this now "DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]"

Comment: I have WP SUper Cache. And even if I remove these .htaccess it seems to do the same problem as i reported below

Answer (score 0):

offtopic, but check the DirectoryIndex directive in the apache docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Hello.. When i go to www.bragtools.com/email/index.php it takes me to www.bragtools.com ! Any idea why?

Comment: This should be placed in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` NOT in `DocumentRoot/email/.htaccess`

Comment: Hello, I did that. Still it goes back to the bragtools.com

Comment: There is no way it can do that since I am using same rule on my live blog. But if you have some other conflicting rules then it might happen. Make sure to place my suggested rule as the first rule in your  `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` and test in different browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: I have a wordpress blog on bragtools.com/blog/ therefore it has its .htacces.I put this .htaccess on bragtools.com sI removed cache and still it didnt work :\

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess in `/email/` also?

Comment: Also WP in installed in `www.bragtools.com/blog/` OR in `www.bragtools.com` also?